# Spring Bean with Factory Method from XML to Java Config

Tags: java, spring

Which is the properly way to *translate* this bean:

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>
```

from XML to Java-Config (note the *factory-method*)?

Is the following solution right?

```
@Bean
public VelocityEngine veloctyEngine() {
        return VelocityFactory.getEngine();
}
```

Is there a better implementation according to the Spring-philosophy?

Cheers, V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are doing it seems right.

Check out [this](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/use-of-factorybeans-with-spring-javaconfig) blog post.